# use M-q in Emacs without turning all my code into comments

Tags: emacs

Say you write some code like this (using ruby-mode, but I've seen this happen in other modes too):

```
# This is a comment.
def foo
    puts "foo!"
end
```

If you put the point on the first line and hit M-q, you get this:

```
# This is a comment. def foo puts "foo!" end
```

How do I avoid that? I'm using version 21.3.

Clarification: This does not happen when I add a blank line between the comment and the code. As a work-around when I want to refill my comments, I go through an annoying three step process:

1. I add a blank line before and after
   the comment paragraph
2. M-q
3. delete the blank lines

It'd be much nicer if M-q handled refilling comment paragraphs without having to add and delete blank lines. Emacs already know what text is comment text, so there must be a way to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I added this info to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[filladapt.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillAdapt) does the trick.  That with the latest version of [RubyMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RubyMode).

Using those two packages solves the M-q problem you're seeing.  (Using GNU Emacs 22.1)

Looking at the code for ruby-mode, it looks like it has customized the variables to control paragraph filling like so:

```
(make-local-variable 'paragraph-start)
(setq paragraph-start (concat "$\\|" page-delimiter))
(make-local-variable 'paragraph-separate)
(setq paragraph-separate paragraph-start)
(make-local-variable 'paragraph-ignore-fill-prefix)
(setq paragraph-ignore-fill-prefix t)
```

Which can be added to a custom hook for your current ruby, or whatever major mode where you want fill behavior to act as you described - provided you use filladapt.el.

Answer (score 1):

M-q is bound to fill-paragraph, what it is doing is trying to do is intelligently turn the text into a paragraph.  It has features that try to guess the 'fill-prefix, which is what appears to be happening to you.

You can unbind M-q if you don't like it.

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-q"))
```

Comment: I like M-q, but it behaves weirdly when I use it on comments that are not separated from code by a blank line.

Comment: Heh - there's a new answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Filling comments works in `sh-mode`.

Perhaps you should submit a bug to the `ruby-mode` maintainer?

Comment: I tried the same thing in sh-mode and got the same result :( .

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in Ruby mode, so that Emacs will understand that “`# This is a comment.`” is a comment. If you are in fundamental mode, it will just treat everything as a text paragraph, which makes it think that the text on the next line is part of the same paragraph.

[Here are](http://blog.modp.com/2007/09/ruby-mode-for-emacs.html) some instructions for installing Ruby mode if you don't already have it.

Comment: That happens even when I'm in Ruby mode.